# Why mysql explain analyze is not working?

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, query-optimization

Besides having mariadb 10.1.36-MariaDB I get following error.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE select 1
MySQL said: Documentation

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ANALYZE select 1' at line 1
```

What additional I need to do here. My PHP version is 7.2.11.

Comment: you need to check your SQL query, please post your query so anyone can help you with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see in the docs  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain-analyze/

> The syntax for the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` feature was changed to `ANALYZE` statement, available since MariaDB 10.1.0. See [`ANALYZE` statement](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/analyze-statement/).

So just use `ANALYZE ...` without the explain keyword and you'll get the same output you got in the past.

In [the analyze docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/analyze-statement/) you have the info for the `ANALYZE` statement, you can see it's the same that the deprecated `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

> The `ANALYZE` statement is similar to the `EXPLAIN` statement. `ANALYZE` statement will invoke the optimizer, execute the statement, and then produce `EXPLAIN` output instead of the result set. The `EXPLAIN` output will be annotated with statistics from statement execution.
>
> The syntax is
>
> `ANALYZE explainable_statement;`
>
> where the statement is any statement for which one can run EXPLAIN.

Comment: Still doesn't work. `SELECT * FROM location` works. `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM location` works. Neither `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` or just `ANALYZE` works, both throw syntax errors.

Comment: @JeneralJames have you ever figured it out?

Comment: @JeneralJames have the same issue; any chance this was figured out?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in mysql older versions(5), can be resolved by upgrading to mysql version 8.
see official discussion https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=97416